# Dynamic component within dynamic component as parent-child

Tags: angular

I was wondering if there is a way to render dynamic component with in dynamic component?

```
<parent-comp>
   <child-1>
    <child-1.1></child-1.1>
    <child-1.2></child-1.2>
   </child-1>
</parent-comp>
```

Above is a kind of representation which I have to achieve.
[this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXsIWykqKZi5r75VMtw2?p=preview) is what I am following to do, while looking into it, with in the **dynamic-component.ts** to the template :

```
<div #dynamicComponentContainer></div>
```

is where the dynamic component being created.

I am trying to acheive something like :

```
<div #dynamicComponentContainer>
     <div #dynamicComponentContainer>
     </div>
</div>
```

A parent-child for dynamic component itself. Can some one give me suggestion on onto achieve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540197/angular2-loading-components-dynamically-from-a-service-response

Comment: Is this what you want https://plnkr.co/edit/53C5gMqfCxoqwuyUyCbQ?p=preview

Comment: @micronyks, in that the children are sibling for each other. what if we need another child for the child as well, not as sibling.