# How to load a module in Angular 2+ dynamically without router?

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading

I have a number of modules that I want to lazy load on to a single page. They may load into any one of several pages in different configurations. They may be pretty heavy, so I don't want them to all load initially. Router wouldn't be appropriate for this situation. How do I lazily load them manually without router?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Loading components dynamically from a service response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540197/angular2-loading-components-dynamically-from-a-service-response)

Comment: This may also be a solution: https://medium.com/@tudorgergely/injecting-components-dynamically-in-angular-2-3d36594d49a0

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat is not the same. The other question is about components, here he is asking about modules (can contain components, directives, pipes, services, other modules).