# Angular2 Destroy Current Component Completely

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried searching google and stackoverflow but could not find an answer. So my question is simple "How can i remove current component in angular 2, 4"

example:

```
<div (click)="remove($event)">Remove Current Component</div>

remove($event) {
    // this.destroy() ????
}
```

Basically what i want is `ComponentRef` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37540287/1635676) `ngOnDestroy()` which calls `this.cmpRef.destroy()` :

```
ngOnDestroy() {
   if(this.cmpRef) {
     this.cmpRef.destroy();
   }    
}
```

But he is getting the `ComponentRef` due to dynamically creating the component.

Comment: just navigate away from the component it will be destroyed

Comment: i'm not using `router` i'm just adding it in the DOM

Comment: I have the same concern when closing an overlay

Answer (score 21):

You can use a `*ngIf="myBoolean"` directive on the component element in the parent template. When `myBoolean` becomes `false`, the component will be destroyed.

No more component or DOM element present. (and `ngOnDestroy` event raised)

If `myBoolean` becomes `true` again, a new component will be instantiated.

A new one will appear in DOM (and `ngOnInit` event raised)

Your click event can emit an event (binded in the parent with the (myEventEmitter) syntax, and a method **in the parent component** can then just set the boolean to `false`.

Demonstration on [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/euZl5yDViJ7WOWJLznQV?p=preview). If it doesn't suit your need, consider editing your question to provide more specific details, including a [Minimal Complete Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i can't use *ngIf, i want it to completely remove it from the context of angular and DOM

Comment: but the ngIf does precisely that, no ? No more DOM component.

Comment: yes but the reference exists in the angular for later use of `*ngIf` i want component to completely `destory`

Comment: But ComponentRef represents reference to **instances** of component. Destroy deletes **instances** of components I am not sure you can do what you want easily (though I would gladly delete this comment and my answer if it turns out to be possible)... Maybe dynamically remove the Module from your application would be the way to go

Comment: but apparently that not possible yet : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/C0TKsfNOVh4

Comment: anyway, I don't understand why you want to do that. Does the Component source javascript code contains sensitive information that you want to remove from the browser ?

Comment: the component is joint with `jsPlumb` that's why i have to remove it.

Comment: so it's not a Angular Component ? (declared in a Typescript file with `@Component() export class MyComponent {}`)

Comment: what do you mean, it is joint with it? doesn't make sense. For example if you use `<ng-container *ngIf="included"> ***your component / markup***</ng-container>` there will be nothing in your DOM left of your markup.

Comment: it is a angular component which is joined with jsPlumb!

Comment: `this.jsPlumbInstance.addEndpoint(`component-child-element`);` which joins it with the component, now i want this `endPoint` to remove which i can use `jsPlumb` event called `remove(selector)` but after that i also want this component to destroy got it ?

Comment: What does it mean "joins with the component" ? Does it create something more in DOM inside the Angular component DOM Element ?

Comment: @TouqeerShafi no i don't "got it". There is NO difference at all in destroying a dynamically created component via its ref or using the `*ngIf` directive on a parent element which does it for you.

Comment: i can't use `*ngIf` because if it has 300 same endpoints then want ?? should i use `*ngIf` for all the components ?? the question is simple `How can i destory the current component from DOM`

Comment: @TouqeerShafi So... The solution by ngIf ** is the correct way**, it destroys the component instance and **everything** in the DOM

Comment: But `*ngIf` will remain there right. any ways thanks for your suggestion i'll see what i can do.

Comment: well, you can have an *ngIf for each component instance. You can create a wrapper component to help you manage all the components, or use *ngFor with a "template selector" containing the *ngIf. Anyway, this would be the correct Angular way to go.

Comment: "the *ngIf will remain there right" -> no, it will not

Comment: @TouqeerShafi I have written a [Plunker to demonstrate the point](https://plnkr.co/edit/euZl5yDViJ7WOWJLznQV?p=preview). Please, if it doesn't demonstrate the correct behavior you want, you should edit it or create another one to show some details of what you want to avoid.

Comment: Hi, it looks like your plunker does not work anymore. But i have the exact same situation that you have described in my application, but ngOnDestroy never gets called. I also added a piece of code that prints something once per second and i found that if the *ngIf condition changes to false and than back to true, the pervious component still exists and continues to print its message, and in addition a new one gets created, so then there are two even though only one exists in DOM.

Comment: @jgosar Yes, I noticed the plunker isn't wokring too. About your issue, I think it would deserve it's own question. Are you able to create a [mcve] on plunker or stackblitz ? that would be great.

Comment: Such a simple and straight forward trick - why did I not think about that myself?! NgIf does the job. Thanks!

Comment: This solution wouldn't work if we were talking about a component being created using `MatDialog`